# Array not sent all element, only get 1st one

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I want to get all posts id from current page after 15 second interval to make server side php query. Php query will find match in Sql with id and if any data find for a particular id's, it will be .append it.

So in my current page have many div with their own dynamic post id like:

```
<div class="case" data-post-id="111"></div>

<div class="case" data-post-id="222"></div>

<div class="case" data-post-id="333"></div>

<div class="case" data-post-id="anything else dynamic no"></div>
```

And I want, my javascript will get and sent this ids to a php query for find any match in Sql.

Here my `array` only got 1st post id. Problem is either my javascript array or php array

My update script: (here `var CID` cannot get ids, only get first id)

```
//make array to get id
var CID = []; //get dynamic id 
$('div[data-post-id]').each(function (i) {
    CID[i] = $(this).data('post-id');
});

function addrep(type, msg) {
    CID.forEach(function (id) {
        $("#newreply" + id).append("");
    });
}
var tutid = '<?php echo $tutid; ?>';

function waitForRep() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/server.php",
        cache: false,
        data: {
            tutid: tutid,
            // this way array containing all ID's can be sent:
            cid: CID
        },
        timeout: 15000,
        success: function (data) {
            addrep("postreply", data);
            setTimeout(
            waitForRep,
            15000);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            setTimeout(
            waitForRep,
            15000);
        }
    });
}
```

server.php

```
if($_REQUEST['tutid'] && $_REQUEST['cid']){
    //make array to cid to get id
    foreach($_REQUEST['cid'] as $key => $value){

       $res = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM test WHERE id =".$value." AND page_id=".$_REQUEST['tutid']." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));

        $rows =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);  

        $row[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $rows); //line 80
        $data = array();

        $data['id'] = $rows['id']; 
        //etc all

            //do something

if (!empty($data)) {
    echo json_encode($data);
    flush();
    exit(0);
}
} }
```

Comment: The array is built correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/k5mo22Lc/, although you could shorten it by using `map()`. Have you checked what data is being retrieved by the server?

Comment: How to check it sir. Is my php array is OK in server.php file?

Comment: in your php file, do print_r($_REQUEST['cid']); exit; -> what does this print?

Comment: Yes there is problem at your server.php file.You echo inside the loop, and after first iteration, the exit statement halts the script

Comment: @koc please check my previous comment

Comment: Browser Network response display `<b>Warning</b>:  array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array in <b>/home/mywebr/server2.php</b> on line <b>80</b><br />
Array
(
    [0] => 1345
    [1] => 1344
    [2] => 1216
)' by `print_r($_REQUEST['cid']); exit;`

Answer (score 0):

Change small code and check it

```
//make array to get id
var CID = []; //get dynamic id 
$('div[data-post-id]').each(function (i) {
    CID[CID.length] = $(this).data('post-id');
});
```